# Running goroutines until valid result from one of them

Tags: go

Is there a way to run some goroutines until one of them returns valid value(integer higher than zero)?
inside a goroutine i'm to guess a number that i need to put inside math formula

Comment: Yes there is. What have you tried? What problems are you facing? Just launch multiple goroutines, each which should deliver the result(s) on a channel. When you get what you want, signal cancellation with a channel or with a `context.Context`.

Comment: @icza if i will send a cancel signal into a channel only one goroutine will get it, isnt it?

Comment: Close the designated channel, and all goroutines trying to receive from it will "get the message". Receiving from a closed channel can proceed immediately (yielding the zero value of the channel's element type).

Comment: @icza thanks, i got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write this yourself.

A goroutine runs until it returns.  Each goroutine decides for itself when to return.

Suppose you have functions/procedures A, B, and C, each of which does a long computation and one of the three might find a useful answer first and the other two should stop if so.  In that case, you'll want to spin off three goroutines which do the computing:

```
func doA(args) {
    ... do computing for A ...
    ... deliver a result ...
    return  // this line is redundant, and here only for illustration
}

func doB(args) {
    ... do computing for B ...
    ... deliver a result ...
}
```

and so on.

What goes in the `args`?  Well, that's up to you, but it's a good idea to give all three functions some way to find out that one of the others has delivered a useful answer and they should stop.  A pretty clever way to do this is to have a channel that someone—whoever decides that a result is "useful", for instance—*closes* to indicate that everyone else should stop working.  All of the `do` functions can then look like this:

```
func doA(done chan struct{}, other_args) {
    var result_ready bool

    for !result_ready {
        select {
        case <-done: // someone else delivered a good result
            return   // so stop working now
        default:
            ... work a bit more ...
        }
    }
    ... deliver result ...
}
```

That still leaves the "deliver result" part.  Where does the result go?  That's up to you too, but a good way to handle this is to have a channel into each routine can put a result when they have one.

There are some tricks to consider here.  Suppose that the `main` driver wants to look at multiple results and pick one that is "good enough" by some measure we don't want to encode into each worker.  Each worker should do some work and send an answer-so-far, and then *keep working* until `main` says "I like one of the answers I got" by `main` closing the `done` channel.  Then we end up with a code structure like this:

```
func doA(done chan struct{}, resultChan chan resulttype, args) {
    for {
        select {
        case <-done:
            return
        default:
             ... do a little work ...
             ... try to deliver result-so-far ...
        }
    }
}
```

The *try to deliver result-so-far* should read like this:

```
select {
case <-done:
    return
case resultChan <- result:
}
```

This might well eliminate the need for the earlier `select`: we have the thing that computes `A` compute until it has a result ready, *then* handle either "you can quit now" or "your result is being sent", whichever occurs first.  If "you can quit" occurs first, it quits.  If "your result is being sent", it gets right back to work on the *next* problem.

At worst, `doA` runs a little longer than it needs to: however long it takes to get one result.

Note that the concept of a "done channel", along with a lot of other scaffolding that is useful in many real programs, is contained in the idea of a *context*.  See [Go Concurrency Patterns: Context](https://blog.golang.org/context) and, relating more directly to your own problem here, [Go Concurrency Patterns: Pipelines and cancellation](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines).